# preg_replace function for multiple matches in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the base64 code for the insert image string using summer note js editor.

I manage to get this

```
preg_replace('#<img\ssrc="data:image/([\w]+);base64,([a-zA-Z0-9+/-_=]+)"\sstyle="width:\s[0-9]+px;">#',"IMAGE REMOVED FROM CHROME\r\n", $content,-1, $counter);
```

As well as a few variations depending on `<img src="data:img/jpg;base65string style="width" data-filename>`.

The position of the `style` and `data-filename` and `src` are always changing depending on different browsers and so I have a few variations.

1. Are there easier ways to do this?

   Like if I have all components of img `src`, `style` and `data-filename`, I will just match the string? I can create all the variations but if I were to do `$content = preg_replace` 10 times for 10 different variations, isn't it extremely slow just to find one match? And it becomes increasingly slower if my `$string` is extremely long.
2. I need to pull out the base64 string to save it as a image, how can I use the regex above to help me to `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`?

Comment: Out-of-order can be done with regex. The real question is what in the world are you trying to extract? Be specific.

Comment: I want to replace the Img string with <file removed> in the text string then offer the image to be downloaded elsewhere. I need The base 64 string for the image file, the data file name, the extension, if available to create the file, if not i use No File Name.imgextension. I believe once the file is created I can find the height and width.

Comment: I think I get the replace working, just not very efficient since my regex string is dependent on the order. So I have about 9 regex expression some with/without data-file name since if used paste into text field some browser don't provide filename

Comment: The thing is when I use 9 different regex I try use preg_match_all I don't seem to get the arrays in the correct order so I have 10 different if else loop

Comment: A quick solution is `<img\s+([^>]+)>`, then in a callback, modify $1 using another replace, then return `"<img " + modified + ">"`

Comment: sorry i do not understand since [^>]+ just put in array $1 whatever that is in my string without the <img> tag.

Comment: No _array_ invlolved, use `preg_replace_callback`. Inside the callback function, use a global replace on $1 for the parts `style and data-filename`, return the replacement as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
<img(\s+src="data:image/([\w]+);base64,([\w+/-_=]+)")?(\s+style="width:\s*([\d]+)px;")?\s*>
```

You can look at this [working example](https://regex101.com/r/dR1uR5/1).

This way, it covers the absence of `src` and/or `style` attributes.
It's up to you to eventually refine it to:

- change the 2 attribute groups to non-capturing, depending on how you find them useful or not
- also make their contents partially optional, or even optionally richer (e.g. `style` might include other properties)

Some additional points:

- in order to face any case, I replaced `\s` by `\s+` between attributes, and at the opposite by `\s*` inside of `style`
- I simplified `[a-zA-Z0-9+/-_=]+` and `[0-9]+` expressions, which become `[\w+/-_=]+` and `[\d]+`
- I added capturing parenthesis around this last one (from your question, seems that you need to get width when available)